Subgroups and corresponding subfields of Galois group of $x^5-5x^2-3$
I think I have found the correct Galois group of $f(x) = x^5-5x^2-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to be $D_5$.
generators are $σ=(1\ 2\ 4\ 5\ 3)$ and $τ=(2\ 3)(4\ 5)$

I can write down the elements of the permutation group $D_5=\{1,σ, σ^2,σ^3, σ^4,τ, σ  τ,σ^2  τ, σ^3  τ , σ^4  τ\}$
Let $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5$ be roots of $f$ and $r_1\in\Bbb R,r_2=\overline{r_3},r_4=\overline{r_5}$.
Then $D_5$ has 6 proper subgroups: five of them are of order $2$, and one normal subgroup $C_5$.
So $τ$ acts by complex conjugation. So the fixed field of $⟨τ⟩$ has degree $5$ over $\Bbb Q$ and contains $\Bbb Q[r_1]$, but $[\Bbb Q[r_1]:\Bbb Q]=5$, so the fixed field of $⟨τ⟩$ is $\Bbb Q[r_1]$.
So the fixed field of $⟨στ⟩,⟨σ^2τ⟩,⟨σ^3τ⟩,⟨σ^4τ⟩$ are $\Bbb Q[r_2],\Bbb Q[r_3],\Bbb Q[r_4],\Bbb Q[r_5]$ in some order.
Since $D_5\subseteq A_5$, the discriminant is a square.
Since $D_5$ doesn't have a subgroup of index $4$, the splitting field $K$ of $f$ doesn't contain a 5th root of unity $\zeta_5$. Although $\sum_j\zeta_5^jr_j$ appears to be fixed by $σ$, it doesn't lie in $K$.
I'm not sure what is the fixed field of $⟨σ⟩$.
Related question: Prove that the Galois Group Is $D_{10}$

@Justauser No, I think whole $D_5$ is contained in $A_5$

@Justauser $\sqrt{\Delta}\in\Bbb Q$

The fixed field of $⟨σ⟩$ is $\Bbb Q[\sum_{j=1}^5\sigma^j(r_1^2r_2)]$.
f = QQbar['x'](x^5 - 5*x**2 - 3)
roots = [f.roots()[n-1][0] for n in [1,2,4,5,3]]
expr = sum([roots[i]**2*roots[(i+1)%5] for i in range(5)])
expr.minpoly()

We get the minimal polynomial of $\sum_{j=1}^5\sigma^j(r_1^2r_2)$ is$$x^2+5 x+100$$
Calculating the discriminant for this quadratic polynomial $\sqrt{5^2-4\times100}=5\sqrt{-15}$, we find
$$\Bbb Q\left[\sum_{j=1}^5\sigma^j(r_1^2r_2)\right]=\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-15}]$$

To verify this:
Factor $x^2+15$ in $K$ by SageMath
# Define the polynomial ring and the polynomial
R.<x> = QQ[]
f = x^5 - 5*x^2 - 3

# Get the splitting field of the polynomial
K.<a> = f.splitting_field()

# Define the polynomial to be factored over the splitting field
g = K['x'](x^2 + 15)

# Factor the polynomial over the splitting field
g.factor()

Output:
$(x - \frac{1}{15} a^{5} - \frac{1}{3} a^{3}) \cdot (x + \frac{1}{15} a^{5} + \frac{1}{3} a^{3})$
$a$ is a root of $x^{10} + 10x^8 + 25x^6 + 3375$.
To verify that it is splitting field (the Galois closure of root field):
f = QQ['x'](x^5 - 5*x**2 - 3)
K.<a>=f.root_field()
L.<b>=K.galois_closure()
L

